# ImageView zoom to match width with moving up & down

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I have images that have height much greater than width. They can perfectly fit in an `ImageView` with portrait orientation with `fitXY`.

However, my problem is with landscape orientation. My best scale I tried is `centerCrop`. Now I have a small problem: I want to give the user the ability to move up & down, because the height is not fit within screen.

How can I do that?

**Note:** The pages are in fact book pages. That is why I want to move up & down. I want to initially fit width, with top of image viewed. Then the user can move down to read rest of page.

Answer (score 0):

I found now this perfect open source [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)